# Convert csv to parquet files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs

I have a Postgres DB and I want to export the tables to files in the format of parquet, and Postgres does not support parquet natively, so I exported the data in CSV format, yet of now I am not able to find a solution in NodeJs/NestJS to convert these files into parquet format.

I found tons of solutions using Python but don't wanna get out of NodeJS for this requirement.

Postgres version: 14,
NodeJS version: >= 16.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [Parquetjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs) library and works pretty well.